# How to convert binary data to an integral value

Tags: c++, stl, integer, type-conversion, binary-data

## Question

What is the best way to convert binary to it's integral representation?

### Context

Let's imagine that we have a buffer containing binary data obtained from an external source such as a socket connection or a binary file. The data is organised in a well defined format and we know that the first four octets represent a single unsigned 32 bit integer (which could be the size of following data). What would be the more efficient way to covert those octets to a usable format (such as std::uint32_t)?

### Example

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::array<char, 4> buffer = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 };
    std::uint32_t n = 0;

    n |= static_cast<std::uint32_t>(buffer[0]);
    n |= static_cast<std::uint32_t>(buffer[1]) << 8;
    n |= static_cast<std::uint32_t>(buffer[2]) << 16;
    n |= static_cast<std::uint32_t>(buffer[3]) << 24;
    std::cout << "Bit shifting:  " << n << "\n";

    n = 0;
    std::memcpy(&n, buffer.data(), buffer.size());
    std::cout << "std::memcpy(): " << n << "\n";

    n = 0;
    std::copy(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), reinterpret_cast<char*>(&n));
    std::cout << "std::copy():   " << n << "\n";
}
```

On my system, the result of the following program is

```
Bit shifting:  67305985
std::memcpy(): 67305985
std::copy():   67305985
```

1. Are they all standard compliant or are they using implementation defined behaviour?
2. Which one is the more efficient?
3. Is there an bette way to make that conversion?

Comment: Are there a couple of typos there?  You have `buffer[1]` 3 times and then later you say `std::sort(): 16854009` instead of `std::copy`.

Comment: You should use another "test array". Using `{ 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01 }` will allmost never fail when converting it, since the four bytes are equal. Use something like `{ 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 }`. Using this last array, only the bit shifting technique gives the correct result(at least on my PC's architecture).

Comment: @fontanini: What is the "correct" result for {0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4}? The OP didn't specify the byte order. If the "well defined format" is little endian, the memcpy approaches are correct but the bit shifting is not.

Comment: @GuyGreer You are right, I have just updated my post.

Comment: @DavidHammen that's why i said that the bit shifting technique gives the correct result **in my PC**. That array gives me "16909060" as a result, which is the hex value `0x01020304`, that's what I would expect from the conversion. Memcpy/std::copy give me "67305985" -> `0x04030201`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You essentially are asking about *endianness*. While your program might work on one computer, it might not on another. If the "well defined format" is network order, there are a standard set of macros/functions to convert to and from network order to the natural order for your specific machine.